# Google Maps Polygon - redraw after adding new points

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a script, where I need to be able to draw a poligon.
Here is the [current script](http://jsfiddle.net/zoli/98nzyg4d/5/).

When I add a new point, a new poligon is drawn over the old one, instead of redraw the current polygon with the new point added.
I tried to add

```
    poligon.setMap(null);
```

before creating the new poligon is created, but then the polygon will not apear at all.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I am new to Google maps API, so please be gentle.

Thanks a lot for your help.

code snippet:

```js
var coords = [];
var poligonCoords = [];
var map = null;
var poligon = null;

function getMinX(a) {
  var ar = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ar.push(a[i].x);
  }
  return Math.min.apply(Math, ar);
}

function getMaxX(a) {
  var ar = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ar.push(a[i].x);
  }
  return Math.max.apply(Math, ar);
}

function getMinY(a) {
  var ar = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ar.push(a[i].y);
  }
  return Math.min.apply(Math, ar);
}

function getMaxY(a) {
  var ar = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ar.push(a[i].y);
  }
  return Math.max.apply(Math, ar);
}

function getCoords() {
  jQuery('ul#coords li').each(function() {
    var x = jQuery(this).children('input:first-child').val();
    var y = jQuery(this).children('input:last-child').val();
    coords[coords.length] = {
      "x": x,
      "y": y
    };
  });
}

function setPoligon() {
  if (!poligon) {}
  for (i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i].x, coords[i].y);
    poligonCoords.push(point);
  }
  poligon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: poligonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  poligon.setMap(map);
}

function initialize() {

  getCoords();

  var minX = getMinX(coords);
  var minY = getMinY(coords);

  var maxX = getMaxX(coords);
  var maxY = getMaxY(coords);

  centerX = minX + ((maxX - minX) / 2);
  centerY = minY + ((maxY - minY) / 2);
  if (!centerX || !centerY) {
    centerX = 46.361416;
    centerY = 25.802191;
  }
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(centerX, centerY),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true
  };


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  setPoligon();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event) {
    var ev = event.latLng;
    document.getElementById("latLong").innerHTML = "" + ev.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + ev.lng().toFixed(6) + "";
    jQuery("ul#coords").append(jQuery("ul#coords li:first-child").clone());
    jQuery("ul#coords li:last-child").children('input:first-child').val(ev.lat().toFixed(6));
    jQuery("ul#coords li:last-child").children('input:last-child').val(ev.lng().toFixed(6));
    getCoords();
    setPoligon();
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 20%;
      }
      #info {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 1em;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ececec;
        border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 .5em #636363;
        overflow: auto;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id='info'>
  <div class='row'>
    <ul id='coords'>
      <li>X:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.216917'>Y:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.728241'>
      </li>
      <li>X:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.214539'>Y:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.729388'>
      </li>
      <li>X:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.211428'>Y:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.730610'>
      </li>
      <li>X:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.209813'>Y:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.725277'>
      </li>
      <li>X:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.209296'>Y:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.717523'>
      </li>
      <li>X:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.213830'>Y:
        <input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.722928'>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  Info: <span id='latLong'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I included the problem, the desired behavior and the code to a jsfiddle. Should I include the code directly in the question?

Comment: Yes.  I edited the post to include  the code from  the fiddle. A link  to a fiddle is  useful, but the code to reproduce the problem  needs to be in the question itself (if the jsfiddle disappears, the question still needs to make sense and be answerable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are never clearing out the coords array, so every time you add a new polygon you get another duplicate set of coordinates in it.

Change:

```
function getCoords(){
    jQuery('ul#coords li').each(function(){
        var x = jQuery(this).children('input:first-child').val();
        var y = jQuery(this).children('input:last-child').val();
        coords[coords.length] = { "x":x, "y":y };
    });
}
```

To:

```
function getCoords(){
    coords = [];
    jQuery('ul#coords li').each(function(){
        var x = jQuery(this).children('input:first-child').val();
        var y = jQuery(this).children('input:last-child').val();
        coords[coords.length] = { "x":x, "y":y };
    });
}
```

Add:

```
if(!!poligon && !!poligon.setMap){
    poligon.setMap(null);
    poligonCoords = [];
}
```

and the map property to your existing polygon.

working code snippet:

```js
var coords=[];
var poligonCoords = [];
var map = null;
var poligon = null;

function getMinX(a) {
 var ar = [];
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  ar.push(a[i].x);
 }
    return Math.min.apply(Math,ar);
}

function getMaxX(a){
 var ar = [];
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  ar.push(a[i].x);
 }
    return Math.max.apply(Math,ar);
}

function getMinY(a) {
 var ar = [];
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  ar.push(a[i].y);
 }
    return Math.min.apply(Math,ar);
}

function getMaxY(a){
 var ar = [];
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  ar.push(a[i].y);
 }
    return Math.max.apply(Math,ar);
}

function getCoords(){
    coords = [];
 jQuery('ul#coords li').each(function(){
  var x = jQuery(this).children('input:first-child').val();
  var y = jQuery(this).children('input:last-child').val();
  coords[coords.length] = { "x":x, "y":y };
 });
}

function setPoligon(){
 if(!!poligon && !!poligon.setMap){
        poligon.setMap(null);
        poligonCoords = [];
 }
 for(i=0;i< coords.length;i++){
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng( coords[i].x, coords[i].y );
  poligonCoords.push(point);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:point,map:map,title:"marker "+i});
 }
 poligon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map:map,
     paths: poligonCoords,
     strokeColor: '#FF0000',
     strokeOpacity: 0.8,
     strokeWeight: 3,
     fillColor: '#FF0000',
     fillOpacity: 0.35
 });
 
 poligon.setMap(map); 
}

function initialize() {

 getCoords(); 

 var minX = getMinX(coords);
 var minY = getMinY(coords);
 
 var maxX = getMaxX(coords);
 var maxY = getMaxY(coords);
 
 centerX =  minX + ((maxX - minX) / 2);
 centerY = minY + ((maxY - minY) / 2);
 if(!centerX || !centerY){
  centerX = 46.361416; centerY = 25.802191;
 }
 var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 16,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(centerX, centerY),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
     scaleControl: true,
     streetViewControl: true
 };


 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 setPoligon();
   
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event) {
  var ev = event.latLng;
     document.getElementById("latLong").innerHTML = "" + ev.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " +ev.lng().toFixed(6)+ "";
     jQuery("ul#coords").append(jQuery("ul#coords li:first-child").clone());
     jQuery("ul#coords li:last-child").children('input:first-child').val(ev.lat().toFixed(6));
     jQuery("ul#coords li:last-child").children('input:last-child').val(ev.lng().toFixed(6));
     getCoords();
     setPoligon();
 });
 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 20%;
      }
      #info {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 1em;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ececec;
        border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 .5em #636363;
        overflow: auto;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id='info'>
     <div class='row'>
      <ul id='coords'>
       <li>X: <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.216917'> Y:<input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.728241'></li>
       <li>X: <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.214539'> Y:<input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.729388'></li>
       <li>X: <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.211428'> Y:<input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.730610'></li>
       <li>X: <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.209813'> Y:<input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.725277'></li>
       <li>X: <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.209296'> Y:<input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.717523'></li>
       <li>X: <input type='text' name='coords[][x]' value='46.213830'> Y:<input type='text' name='coords[][y]' value='25.722928'></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     Info: <span id='latLong'></span>
</div>
```